# Unable to start session for jupyter kernel python vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have looked at other issues posted on stack overflow and github:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/728
[Unable to start Jupyter notebook on VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63707774/unable-to-start-jupyter-notebook-on-vs-code)

A lot of people could run this command:

```
python -m pip install 'traitlets==4.3.3' --force-reinstall
```

And this would resolve issues with the jupyter kernel not loading within vscode.

I consistently have issues connecting to the kernel and after a period of time I am presented with a message:

```
Unable to start session for kernel Python 3.7.4 64 bit ('name_of_virtual_environment'). Select another kernel to launch with.
```

I am using wsl 2 with ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have selected the correct python interpreter (for the python extension and in the actual notebook). I am also using pyenv to create my virtual environments.
vscode version 1.52.1

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/728 all the way through? For instance, did you fully close out VS Code, so that when you force-reinstall traitlets 4.3.3, you get a fresh install?

Comment: yes I fully closed vscode and force reinstalled traitlets 4.3.3, I have found that this issue persists with only one of my virtual environments. I believe that this might be due to conflicting dependencies, for the time being I will just switch the python interpreter in the jupyter notebook itself. This should be a good work around.

Comment: @Amundeep Singh Dhaliwal -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Comment: Hello Jill Cheng. I have been using another kernel from a pyenv virtual environment that I installed ipykernel, ipython and jupyter into. Things are a lot smoother now. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended that you check whether the dependency package "ipykernel" required by Jupyter notebook has been successfully installed in your chosen python environment: ("`pip show ipykernel`")

[image]

Reference: [Jupyter notebook in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

Answer (score 2):

uninstall jupyter and its dependencies, then reinstall them.

```
pip uninstall jupyter
pip uninstall jupyter_core
pip uninstall jupyter-client
pip uninstall jupyter-console
pip uninstall jupyterlab_pygments
pip uninstall notebook
pip uninstall qtconsole
pip uninstall nbconvert
pip uninstall nbformat`
```

reinstall jupyter notebook and plugins

```
pip install jupyter
pip install jupyter_core
pip install jupyter-client
pip install jupyter-console
pip install jupyterlab_pygments
pip install notebook
pip install qtconsole
pip install nbconvert
pip install nbformat
```